# question about bivariate gaussian

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate

I have a bivariate normal distribution

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}\sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{z}{2(1-\rho^{2})}\right) $$

where $$z=\frac{x^2}{\sigma_{1}^2}+\frac{y^2}{\sigma_{2}^2}-\frac{2\rho xy}{\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}}$$

Is there a simple way to calculate way to calculate the standard deviation of the difference (x-y) ?

Comment: What is the truncation that you are applying to the formula you are exhibiting? The joint pdf formula that you have shown is a valid pdf only if the support is the entire plane and not if the support only part of the plane.

Comment: sorry, i edited the post. There is not trucation in my bivariate, that was a "misprint"

Comment: $$ \sqrt{ \sigma_{1}^2 + \sigma_{2}^2 - 2 \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 }$$

Comment: Search for https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+difference for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we have the following equality,  not specific to bivariate Gaussians:
$$\begin{align}\sigma^2_{X-Y}&=\operatorname{var}(X-Y)=\operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)-2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\\&=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2-2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y\end{align}$$Here, we already know the coefficient of correlation, and the deviation of the difference is just the square root of this, which is also noted by @logistic in the comments.

Comment: Thank you to all of you.Just another question. Is there any relationship between var(X-Y) and the variance of the conditional distribution of f(x,y) ?

Comment: do you mean $var(X|Y)$?

Comment: I meant $var(Y|x)$, i.e. i fix x at a certain value (for example x=0), i calculate f(Y,0) and i'm interested in variance of f(Y,0)
Thank you